# installation aborted. signature verification failed android eclipse

Tags: android

First i'll describe the problem:

My boss got a source code from some developers, and he asked me to develope it.

Code is developed in android in Eclipse editor.

Problem is when I try to publish my new version and try to update my application to developing environment it doesn't allow to do so. It says installation aborted. Signature verification failed or something like that.

The smartphone im developing for has old version of this application as FIRMWARE (Versions that has been developed by those other developers) wich are installed when the smartphone is manufactured.

So I can't delete the application from the smartphone, updating is the only way.

What should I do?

Comment: Your signing signature must match if you want to replace an existing app version. Ask for the key or rename the app package so it becomes a different app.

Comment: Ty zapl
the truth is not sure if i can get the signature, so before asking those guys for signature im looking for an other solution.
this application is kinda luncher, when smartphone opened it shows this program, so if i rename package it will be just an ordinary application which thats not the purpose why im developing it.

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of the signature verification. You can't replace system apps unless you have the manufacturers signing key :)